# How to disable "Menu" key in Terminal?

Tags: guake

I am an enthusiastic Guake user - but sometimes I want to access Guake when I have a Terminal window open. Problem is, when I have Terminal focused, and I hit Menu key (which is what I'm using for Guake hotkey), I get a contextual menu within Terminal, instead of Guake.

Is there a way to disable Menu key from doing anything in Terminal? I can't seem to find a preference for this, neither within Terminal or System -> Keyboard preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by switching to the F12 key to display Guake. No more conflicts! Happy :D